# Highlight parts of a text piecewise in beamer

Tags: beamer, highlighting

I'm about to write a presentation with beamer and want to  show a complete sentence first. After that I'd like to highlight one or more words in that sentence to explain them.

My current approach is to use `\onslide*`. However this is quite some manual work and I'd like to know if there is some better solution for this. Could I reveal or highlight those words in another/better way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  \onslide*<1>{This is an example sentence.}
  \onslide*<2>{This is an \textcolor{red}{example} sentence.}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `This is an \textcolor<2>{red}{example} sentence.` is enough. `\textcolor`, like many standard commands, is " overlay aware" in `beamer`.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to the `\textcolor` from [campas comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430764/highlight-parts-of-a-text-piecewise-in-beamer/430774#comment1079255_430764), you could also use `\alert` to highlight things.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}
  This is an \alert<+(1)>{example} sentence.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Is the `\alert<+(1)>` (`(+x)`) syntax a new syntax? Never used it before. Crazy, also `\alert<+(1),+(3)>` works!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner `(x)` can be used as an offset to the overlay.

Comment: I see that now :). I was curious if that was possible from the start of beamer or if this was introduced later. But it's not important - I am just angry at myself for not using it earlier.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner For more information, see `9.6.4 Incremental Specifications` of the user guide

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner :) Don't be angry, there are so many features, nobody can use them all